# JBoss equivalent to Apache's unescapeHtml?

Tags: java, html, jboss, special-characters, escaping

Does anyone know a JBoss equivalent to [Apache's unescapeHTML(String)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29) function?

Comment: Why a "JBoss equivalent"? What stops you from using Apache Commons Lang in your webapp?

Answer (score 0):

No, I placed commons-lang in the servers/lib directory